# How to enable stage 0 in this webpack babel config so that I can use decorators

Tags: webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to follow this example http://jamesknelson.com/unlocking-decorators-and-other-es7-features-with-webpack-and-babel/ with my fluxible app to enable decorators.  I tried adding `query:{stage:0}` as per the instructions to the webpack.config.js but I'm getting an error saying `Cannot define 'query' and multiple loaders in loaders list`

What's the correct way to enable stage:0/decorators in my fluxible babel 5 webpack project?

What's the difference between the .babelrc file and the options passed to the webpack.config?

webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var webpackConfig = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './client.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./build/js'),
        publicPath: '/public/js/',
        filename: 'main.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: [
                    require.resolve('react-hot-loader'),
                    require.resolve('babel-loader')
                ],
                query: {stage: 0}
            },
            { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader'}
        ]
    },
    node: {
        setImmediate: false
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
            }
        })
    ],
    devtool: 'eval'
};

module.exports = webpackConfig;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-optimal solution, but it may be good enough for you as it was for me:

1. Downgrade babel-core and babel-loader to version 5. Specifically in the `package.json` `devDependencies`:

   "babel-core": "5.8.14", 
   "babel-loader": "5.3.2"
2. Add babel config as a top-level property in `package.json`:

   "babel": {
     "stage": 0
   }

The same property could be put in a `.babelrc` file.

Source: Hendrik Swanepoel's Pluralsite course on React and the corresponding repo: https://github.com/hendrikswan/react-stack. In the course he uses alt.js decorators extensively and it works without any warnings.

Again, this isn't a perfect solution because it requires downgrading your dependencies, but it may save you and others some time.

Comment: setting "stage": 0 in the babelrc file without downgrading seems to have worked.

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I overlooked that you said you were already using version 5. However I can confirm the same configuration will not work with version 6+.

Answer (score 0):

There is an instruction on SurviveJS for your setup. I tried it and it worked very well. It may also help you:

> http://survivejs.com/webpack_react/webpack_and_react/

Answer (score 0):

setting `.babelrc` to this worked in my fluxible project

```
{
  "optional": ["es7.classProperties"],
  "stage": 0
}
```